# PyQGIS joining a dbf to a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, attribute-joins, dbf

I am trying to join a shp and dbf file using the PyQGIS API.
The code I'll use is below:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
vector1 = QgsVectorLayer("path to dbf file", "test1", "ogr")
id1 = vector1.id()
print id1
vector2 = QgsVectorLayer("path to shapefile", "test2", "ogr")
id2 = vector2.id()
print id2
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vector1)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vector2)
info = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
info.joinFieldIndex = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(id1).fieldNameIndex("Id1Column0") # Returns 0 as expected
info.joinFieldName = QString(u"Id1Column0")
info.joinLayerId = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(id1).id()
info.targetFieldIndex = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(id2).fieldNameIndex("Id2Column0")  # Returns 0 as expected
info.targetFieldName = QString(u"Id2Column0")
info.memoryCache = True
print info.joinFieldIndex #All the following show the correct values
print info.joinFieldName
print info.joinLayerId
print info.targetFieldIndex
print info.targetFieldName
print info.memoryCache
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(id2).addJoin(info)
```

Querying for the respective field names using QgsVectorLayer.attributeDisplayName(0) yields the respective column names as expected.

Yet when I look in the GUI properties, while the join layer is set correctly, the join field is something different and the target field is empty.

Could anyone shed some light on what goes wrong?

Comment: I am aware of this https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/python/plugins/sextante/algs/JoinAttributes.py but I'd prefer to make as much use of the QGIS API as possible.

Comment: Why are you digging into `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()` when you already have the layer there? `vector2` and `vector1`

Comment: Mostly because the code is copy and pasted from various parts of the program. It's the minimum example which exhibits the problem and the problem also persists when I'd use vector1 and vector2 instead of the Map Layer Registry